# Pass userId from WebUI to DAL using Ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, inversion-of-control

I have a 3 layer application : WebUI, BLL and DAL. I need to pass UserId to DAL from  WebUI layer using Ninject. Composition root is in WebUI layer. 
WebUI depend on BBL and BLL depends on DAL.

So question is how can I pass userId from WebUI to BLL and then to DAL. When the user is authenticated i need to pass UserId, if not authenticated - pass null.

In composition root (WebUI)

```
 private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
            kernel.Bind<ICTOFacade>().To<CTO_Facade>().InRequestScope();
}
```

In BLL :

```
  public class ServiceModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind(typeof(ISingleEntityRepository<>)).
                To(typeof(GenericRepository<>)).InRequestScope();

            Bind(typeof(IMultipleEntitiesRepository<>)).
                To(typeof(GenericRepository<>)).InRequestScope();
        }
    }

public class CTO_Facade : ICTOFacade
    {
        private ISingleEntityRepository<CargoTransportationOrderModel> _ctoRepoSingle;
        private IMultipleEntitiesRepository<CargoTransportationOrderModel> _ctoRepoMultiple;

    public CTO_Facade(ISingleEntityRepository<CargoTransportationOrderModel> singleRepo,
        IMultipleEntitiesRepository<CargoTransportationOrderModel> multipleRepo)
    {
```

In DAL:

```
 public sealed class GenericRepository<T> : ISingleEntityRepository<T>, IMultipleEntitiesRepository<T> where T : BaseModel
    {
        private string _userId;


        #region Helpers

        public GenericRepository(string userId)
        {
            _userId = userId;
        }
...
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Classic ASP, please retag.

Comment: Where is the `userId` comming from? How can you access it? In what scope is it available? Regarding a request cycle, from what time on is it available?

Comment: UserId can be accessed by          calling HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other solutions for this, but i will suggest to you a way more simple to do that, injecting a complex type like this:

```
public class UserDTO
{
   public string Id {get; set;}
   ...
}
```

and then in the constructor of the repo:

```
public sealed class GenericRepository<T> : ISingleEntityRepository<T>, IMultipleEntitiesRepository<T> where T : BaseModel
{
    private UserDTO _currentUser;

    public GenericRepository(UserDTO user)
    {
        _currentUser = user;
    }
   ...
}
```

Setting the `Bind`:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    ...

    kernel.Bind<UserDTO>().ToMethod(ctx => new UserDTO { Id = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId() }).InRequestScope();
}
```

> So i belive that you want to make some default filter or setting default values in your repo, with this `_currentUser.Id` you can get the id of the current user.

Comment: WebUI does not depend on Data Access Layer so I can't use User class defined in WebUI in DAL.

Comment: The `User` class is a example you can use some DTO to do this like `UserDTO` or `CurrentUser`. But you get the idea, right?

Comment: Ok, I got the idea. But what will happen when a user logs out and HttpContext.Current == null?

Comment: So, you can check in the `ctor` of the repo and throws some `ArgumentException`. probaly this repo only can be used when a user is logged